# Get connected Classic Bluetooth device name from iOS settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-bluetooth

I am researching on the same since last 2 to 3 hours but failed to get the success. My requirement is I want to get the connected Classic bluetooth device name in the iOS app.

**Description** :

For example If I have connected my speaker in the iOS settings>Bluetooth. Then I need to display the connected speaker name in the iOS app.
Thank you for spending your time. The below codes which I have tried but not working.

**Code which I tried**

```
NSArray *availInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
int count = [availInputs count];

for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDesc = [availInputs objectAtIndex:k];
    NSLog(@"input%i port type %@", k+1, portDesc.portType);
    NSLog(@"input%i port name %@", k+1, portDesc.portName);
}

NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]
                        connectedAccessories];

for (EAAccessory *obj in accessories)
{
    NSLog(@"Found accessory named: %@", obj.name);
}
```